# Why, my result has the opposite sign to the correct result?

Tags: quadratics, factoring

I found this exercise of factoring:

$$5a^2 + 3a - 2$$ is a trinomial of the form:

$$ax^2 + bx + c  = \frac{(ax + p)(ax + q)}{a}$$

I made this:

$$3 = p + q$$

$$-10 = pq$$

then, I need to get the values of $p$ and $q$.

$$p = -\frac{10}q$$

replace:

$$3 = -\frac{10}q + q$$

$$q^2 -3q - 10 = 0$$

$$(q - 5)(q + 2)$$ That is two possible values of $q$

I need to check the correct value now:

$$3 = p - 5\implies p = -8$$ but $8 \times 5 \neq -10$, so the correct value of $q$ is $2$.

Replace to check if is true:

$$3 = p - 2\implies p = 1$$ but $1 \times -2 \neq -10$

In the end, the correct values impressively were $5$ and $2$, which I had obtained in the equation of $q$, but with a changed sign.
$$p = 5, q = -2$$

So, what am I doing wrong factoring this expression?
Is it a property that the result was that? or was it coincidence

*PD: the total factoring was:* $(a + 1)(5a - 2)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake is when you stated that $(q-5)(q+2)=0$ has solutions $q=-5,q=2$.

Instead, you have $$q-5=0\quad\text{and}\quad q+2=0$$ giving $q=5$ and $q=-2$ and so substituting gives $$3=p+5\implies p=-2\implies pq=-2(5)=-10$$ and $$3=p-2\implies p=5\implies pq=5(-2)=-10$$ as desired.

Comment: It was simpler than I thought, thank you very much!

Comment: Wait, my last question is, why does the second possible value of $q$, is really the value of $p$?

Comment: In this case, the integer factors of $10$ are $\pm(1,2,5,10)$ and since $3-5=-2$ the only other possible pairing must be $5$.

Answer (score 0):

> *the total factoring was*: $\;(a + 1)(5a - 2)$

You could get that directly by finding the roots using the quadratic formula $\,\dfrac{-3 \pm \sqrt{49}}{10}=\begin{cases}-1 \\ 2/5\end{cases}\,$.

Then the quadratic factors as $5\big(a-(-1)\big)\left(a - \dfrac{2}{5}\right)=(a+1)(5a-2)\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] In the general case $\,ax^2 + bx + c  = \dfrac{(ax + p)(ax + q)}{a}\,$ the factorization follows directly from the quadratic formula as well:

$$
\begin{align}
ax^2 + bx + c = a(x-x_1)(x-x_2) &= a\left(x-\frac{-b - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\right)\left(x-\frac{-b + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\right) \\[10px]
 &= \frac{\left(ax + \cfrac{b + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right)\left(ax + \cfrac{b - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right)}{a}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How can I find the result, when the root is not exact? It is very tedious to look for two numbers when the numbers are very high

Comment: @jXiao You can always find the roots of a quadratic when you know the coefficients, however "*tedious*" that may be for large numbers. There is not really a shortcut to that in the general case.

Comment: Oh, thanks dxiv

Comment: @jXiao I added the calculation for the general case at the end.

Comment: many many thanks dxiv

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$5a^2 + 3a - 2= (5a+p)(a+q)=5a^2+(p+5q)a+pq$$

Thus $p+5q=3$ and $  pq=-2$

which implies $q=1$ and $p=-2$

Therefore the factorization is
$$5a^2 + 3a - 2=(5a+p)(a+q)=(5a-2)(a+1)$$

Comment: How did you get directly to $(a + q)$ ? I only know the form as: $\frac{(ax + p)(ax +q)}{a}$

Comment: And why $pq = -2$ instead of $pq = -10$ , that is $5 * -2 $ ?

Comment: With just one $5$ in front of $a^2$, you really do not need to consider two $5$ s and then cancel one of them later.

Comment: well, but why $pq = -2$ instead of $-10$

Comment: because  term by term comparison of $5a^2 + 3a - 2= 5a^2+(p+5q)a+pq$  implies $pq=-2$

Answer (score 0):

I'm satisfied with TheSimplyFire's answer for your question. Also look at the equation you set up:
$$ax^2 + bx + c  = \frac{(ax + p)(ax + q)}{a}$$ Now look at the coefficients of $x$: It is $a$ in the both factors of $x$ on RHS. Thus, $p$ and $q$ should be interchangeable and factors belong to only one of two factor pairs of $-10$. That means, $p\times(q)=2\times(-5)$ or $p\times(q)=5\times(-2)$ or $q\times(p)=2\times(-5)$ or $q\times(p)=5\times(-2)$.

**Note:** Your equation setup can be consider as general form. However, if $a$ in $ax^2 + bx + c$ is a prime number like $5$, you do not have to divide the RHS of the equation again by $a$. Instead, you can setup it as: $$ax^2 + bx + c  = (ax + p)(x + q)$$ This is because any prime number $p$ has one distinctive factor pair: $p\times1$.